# Voltage gain of a vco

Tags: gain, vco

What should be the typical gain of an nmos only LC VCO? Should it be more than 100MHz/V or 200MHz/V or lesser than this? Which is more useful - keeping the gain high or low?

Answer (score 1):

You can always change the gain of the PLL loop.
What are you objectives?

Low gain means your VCO will be less responsive to random noise from your control loop; low gain also means you may have difficulty controlling the center frequency, if you only have 0v--2v from your PLL.

Comment: Your answer is full of questions.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment, rather than an answer. Please only post answers when you have enough information to provide a conclusive answer/solution to the question (or, in fairly rare cases, when it is completely necessary, such as when your commentary would be quite difficult to understand without posting an accompanying circuit diagram).